# Can AS3 call signed and encrypted SOAP web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, actionscript-3

We currently have a C# SOAP web service that needs to be secured. We're planning on adding signing and encryption to the service along with authentication.
We have a number of AS3 applications that needs to call the service. Is there a way to do this? I haven't been able to find any information on it.
If not, I might have to rethink the web service. We need to make sure that the calls, both from and to the service, can't be intercepted and changed.

This is what we plan on using for signing
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819963.aspx

and for encrypting

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824684.aspx

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This quite broad.  Please describe how you are currently signing and encrypting it.      There are encryption/hashing libraries for AS3 so it should be possible

Comment: I added 2 links to the post